# Efficient way to combine intersecting bounding rectangles

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, bounding-box

I'm trying to simplify the following image using OpenCV:

[image]

What we have here are lots of red shapes. Some of them completely contain others. Some of them intersect their neighbors. My goal is to unify all **intersecting** shapes by replacing any two intersecting shapes with the bounding box of their union's polygon. (repeating until there are no more intersecting shapes).

By intersecting I mean also touching. Hope this makes it 100% clear:

[image]

I'm trying to do this efficiently using standard morphology operations; obviously it can be done naively in `O(N^2)`, but that'll be too slow. Dilation doesn't help because some shapes are only 1px apart and I don't want them merged if they're not intersecting.

Comment: What about using the function GroupRectangles (though it works in O(N^2)) ?

Comment: It wouldn't work for the last case - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421070/opencv-grouprectangles-getting-grouped-and-ungrouped-rectangles

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To accomplish what you want we'll be using [`findContours`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours). The key point here is to understand how it works when `mode` is set to `CV_RETR_TREE`. In this case, `hierarchy` is constructed in a way that every even depth level contains *external contours*, while odd depth levels contain *internal contours*. What we need here is to traverse the hierarchy tree printing the contours associated with even depth levels.

First we find the contours of an image called `original`

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > Contours;
typedef std::vector<cv::Vec4i> Hierarchy;

Contours contours;
Hierarchy hierarchy;
cv::findContours(original, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
```

To print the external contours on an image called `processed` we need a recursive function.

```
void printExternalContours(cv::Mat img, Contours const& contours, Hierarchy const& hierarchy, int const idx)
{
    //for every contour of the same hierarchy level
    for(int i = idx; i >= 0; i = hierarchy[i][0])
    {
        //print it
        cv::drawContours(img, contours, i, cv::Scalar(255));

        //for every of its internal contours
        for(int j = hierarchy[i][2]; j >= 0; j = hierarchy[j][0])
        {
            //recursively print the external contours of its children
            printExternalContours(img, contours, hierarchy, hierarchy[j][2]);
        }
    }
}

printExternalContours(processed, contours, hierarchy, 0);
```

The result is shown bellow, where `original` and `processed` are displayed side by side.

[image: original] [image: processed]

If you absolutely need rectangular shapes, you just need to use [`boundingRect`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#boundingrect) to get the minimum enclosing rectangle given a set of points (every single contour in this case) and use [`rectangle`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#rectangle) for the drawing. In other words, substitute

```
cv::drawContours(img, contours, i, cv::Scalar(255));
```

by

```
cv::rectangle(img, cv::boundingRect(contours[i]), cv::Scalar(255));
```

`findContours` expects a single 8-bit image, sou you could either make a gray image from your originals and then threshold it to get a perfect black background or, perhaps it would suffice to use the red channel in your case, just make sure the background is perfectly black.

Regarding the *complexity* of `findContours`, I can't attest it is any better than O(N^2), nor haven't I found any input on that after a quick google search, but I trust OpenCV implements the best known algorithm.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried it but it seems to eliminate contained (yet not intersected) shapes. e.g.: http://i.imgur.com/x5izyFc.png

Comment: @AssafLavie it wasn't clear to me that only intersecting shapes should be unified, but now I see the bold text. Also, do you absolutely need rectangular shapes? Because the `findContours` approach will yield arbitrary poligonal shapes.

Comment: The input is actually the result of a previous call to findContours; I then take the bounding box of each contour.

Comment: @AssafLavie CV_RETR_LIST doesn't work either, let me work on that for a second.

Comment: I wonder if a flood fill algorithm would help here. Use it to "walk" the connected shapes, while keeping track of the bounding box of each shape... (although it's not a filter-based solution)

Comment: @AssafLavie I thought about it, but I can foresee several corner cases, I'm working on a solution based on what I initially proposed, I think it's going to work out, hold on for a moment.

Comment: @AssafLavie I got it to work using `findContours` only, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Awesome. I will port it to Python and try it out. Have you by any chance tested the touching && !intersecting case?

Comment: @AssafLavie yes I'll upload new images

Comment: @AssafLavie  were you able to port this to Python? I am after the same thing.

Comment: @brunocodutra Do you have the code that draws the original image in your answer? It'll be really helpful for that code to be here so someone can play around with `printExternalContours`

Comment: @Omnipresent I'm sorry, but I don't have it anymore, that was almost 3 years ago today

Comment: @brunocodutra I figured, but was worth asking. I'm having the same issue and came here from google. Thanks for your answer anyways.

Answer (score 16):

**UPDATE:** I misunderstood the question earlier. We don't want to remove rectangles which are completely inside others. We only want to replace the **intersecting** rectangles. Therefore for the first case, we have to do nothing.

New api (2.4.9) supports & and | operators.

From [opencv doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#rect):

- rect = rect1 & rect2 (rectangle intersection)
- rect = rect1 | rect2 (minimum area rectangle containing rect2 and rect3 )

It also supports equality comparision (==)

- rect == rect1

So it is now very easy to accomplish the task. For every pair of rectangle rect1 and rect2,

```
if((rect1 & rect2) == rect1) ... // rect1 is completely inside rect2; do nothing.
else if((rect1 & rect2).area() > 0) // they intersect; merge them.
    newrect = rect1 | rect2;
    ... // remove rect1 and rect2 from list and insert newrect.
```

**UPDATE 2:** (for translating in java)

I know java very little. I also never used the java API. I am giving here some psudo-code (which I think can be easily translated)

For `&` operator, we need a method which finds the intersect of two rectangles.

```
Method: Intersect (Rect A, Rect B)
left = max(A.x, B.x)
top  = max(A.y, B.y)
right = min(A.x + A.width, B.x + B.width)
bottom = min(A.y + A.height, B.y + B.height)
if(left <= right && top <= bottom) return Rect(left, top, right - left, bottom - top)
else return Rect()
```

For `|` operator, we need a similar method

```
Method: Merge (Rect A, Rect B)
left = min(A.x, B.x)
top  = min(A.y, B.y)
right = max(A.x + A.width, B.x + B.width)
bottom = max(A.y + A.height, B.y + B.height)
return Rect(left, top, right - left, bottom - top)
```

For `==` operator, we can use overloaded `equals` method.

Comment: This is nice but I do not think he has the rect's coordinates, he would have to detect them first.

Comment: @RuiMarques He actually has the Rect shapes. He mentioned it in a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079619/efficient-way-to-combine-intersecting-bounding-rectangles#comment28205660_19079805).

Comment: I would love to know how to translate the same code in Java! Please help. Skimming through the API but nothing found. Worst case would be JNI-calls.

Comment: Thank @asif for updating the answer. What i'm now trying to do is exploit the OpenCV Java API. The operators theirself are not hard to implement in Java. Let see, how the JNI performance turns out. There are still a lot other functionalities to be ported from C++ library to Java.

Answer (score 5):

Given two bounding box contours in the form of `(x,y,w,h)`, here's a function to create a single bounding box (assuming the boxes are touching or within each other). Returns `(x,y,w,h)` of the combined bounding box i.e, top-left x, top-left y, width, and height. Here's an illustration

```
(x1,y1)       w1                           (x3,y3)         w3
  ._____________________.                    .____________________________.
  |                     |                    |                            | 
  |                     |  h1                |                            |
  |   (x2,y2)           |                    |                            |
  |     ._______________|_______.      -->   |                            |
  |     |               |       |            |                            |  h3
  ._____|_______________.       |            |                            |
        |                       |  h2        |                            |
        |                       |            |                            |
        |           w2          |            |                            |
        ._______________________.            .____________________________.
```

Code

```
def combineBoundingBox(box1, box2):
    x = min(box1[0], box2[0])
    y = min(box1[1], box2[1])
    w = box2[0] + box2[2] - box1[0]
    h = max(box1[1] + box1[3], box2[1] + box2[3]) - y
    return (x, y, w, h)
```

---

**Example**

With these two bounding boxes,

```
>>> print(box1)
>>> print(box2)
(132, 85, 190, 231)
(264, 80, 121, 230)

>>> new = combineBoundingBox(box1, box2) 
>>> print(new)
(132, 80, 253, 236)
```

Here's the visual result: Before `->` After

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is a simple approach. Your answer would be complete if you also mention how to find if two boxes are touching each other.

Comment: doesn't work for all alignement of the rectangles