# Finding the top and bottom y coordinate of a opencv rectangle

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I want to merge [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUMXF.png) 2 rectangles into one, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dei4D.png). The easiest way I can think to do this is getting the top *y* coordinate of the top rectangle and the bottom *y* coordinates of the bottom one and use them in `cv2.rectangle()`, but I am having trouble getting both these points because of a *for loop*.

Here is the code:

```
#Finding contours (always finds those 2 retangles + some noise):
_, conts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_green, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for cnt in conts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)

    #filter all the noise
    if area > 20:

        x1, y1, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        x2 = x1 + w                           # (x1, y1) = top-left vertex
        y2 = y1 + h                           # (x2, y2) = bottom-right vertex
        cv2.rectangle(green_bar_win, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255,0,0), 2)
        print("x1:", x1, " y1:", y1, " x2:", x2, " y2:", y2)
```

Here is the print result (it prints the x,y coordinates of the top-left and bottom-right rectangle points for both rectangles in diferent itinerations of the loop):

```
x1: 60  y1: 217  x2: 83  y2: 288
x1: 60  y1: 169  x2: 83  y2: 216
x1: 60  y1: 217  x2: 83  y2: 288
x1: 60  y1: 169  x2: 83  y2: 216...
```

Thanks.

EDIT: my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48590321/how-to-find-the-center-point-of-this-rectangle?noredirect=1#comment84181081_48590321)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of going with the coordinates, you can do it in a simpler way by using 'or'.

If both of the rectangles are of opencv type rect, you can simply use,

```
result = rect1 | rect2;
```

That will give you a rectangle enclosing both.
Similarly, you can do other operations like

```
result = rect1 & rect2;
```

That'll give you the internsection of both the rectangles.
[Reference.](https://putuyuwono.wordpress.com/2015/06/26/intersection-and-union-two-rectangles-opencv/)

Comment: But how do I give different names for the rectangles? If i do what you are saying it would be `result = rect | rect` because `rect` is the only rectangle drawing that I have. As you can see in:  `rect = cv2.rectangle(green_bar_win, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255,0,0), 2)`

Comment: I've used that in c++. If you want to try that, create a vector of rect and then pushback to it in the loop. Finally you can 'or' all the rect's. Otherwise, check this [LINK](http://answers.opencv.org/question/90455/how-to-perform-intersection-or-union-operations-on-a-rect-in-python/) for python.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve the result, some of it can be the following:

1) From the image, it is very clear that both the rectangles are very close to each other. So the contours must also be very close. Therefore before finding the contours, perform [morphological transformations](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) to the image. Mostly dilation will help. Find the working of this operation in the link.

```
dilation = cv2.dilate(img,kernel,iterations = 1)
```

2) Else if you only want to combine the rectangles, you can follow up with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079619/efficient-way-to-combine-intersecting-bounding-rectangles)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am actually trying to find the big rectangle center point, and I have been thinking after posting my question, would it work if I calculated the center of the 2 smaller rectangles and average them? It would be a lot easier I suppose, because the x coordinates never changes, so I would be dealing only with two 'y' coordinates.

Comment: If you are very sure that only those two rectangles are going to be detected. You can very well merge them both. or find the center point of the large rectangle like that.