# How to find the center point of this rectangle

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to find the center point of the [green rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UR8BP.jpg) which is behind the fish, but my approach is not working. Here is my code:

```
#Finding contours (almost always finds those 2 retangles + some noise):
_, conts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_green, cv2.RETR_TREE , cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for cnt in conts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)

    #filter noise
    if area > 25:

        M = cv2.moments(cnt)
        x1, y1, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        x2 = x1 + w                           # (x1, y1) = top-left vertex
        y2 = y1 + h                           # (x2, y2) = bottom-right vertex
        cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])           # (cx, cy) = rect center
        cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
        rect = cv2.rectangle(green_bar_win, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255,0,0), 2)
        center = cv2.circle(green_bar_win, (cx, cy), 2, (0,0,255), 4)
```

As you can see, it finds the rectangle's contour but divided where the fish is, making 2 different shapes. It also finds the center of this 2 shapes (the blue points), however I don't know how to find the middle of the big one. I thought about averaging all the found rectangle centers but I don't know how to write this out. I am finding the rectangles by hsv color. Help?

EDIT: I have 'y1' from the top rectangle, but don't know how to get y2 from the bottom one while inside the for loop. I tried this:

```
_, conts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_green, cv2.RETR_TREE , cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for cnt in conts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)

    #filter noise
    if area > 25:

        x1, y1, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        x2 = x1 + w                           # (x1, y1) = top-left vertex

        try:
            rect_center = np.average([y1, y2])
        except:
            print("Failed to average")

        y2 = y1 + h                           # (x2, y2) = bottom-right vertex
        rect = cv2.rectangle(green_bar_win, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255,0,0), 2)
```

But it still fails, because y2 is used before assigment. So, how could I get y2 from the second loop itineration before y1 is overwritten by the 'for' loop?

Comment: Your problem is too specific; we need a little more explanation of what you need.  How much interference is acceptable before you *should* see those as separate?

Comment: The simple solution is to post-process the results, looking for shapes to merge: same color, aligned edges, separated by a different shape that we take to be an occlusion.

Comment: But how can I post-process the results based in color or edges?

Comment: If this is the only green object on the scene (as shown on screenshot) - just take top and bottom coordinates of detected rectangles and calculate median.

Comment: You have the color of the contents; you have the bounding box.  Isn't that all the information you need?

Comment: @Prune could you see my new edit please?

Comment: You identified the problem neatly: this is *post*-processing, but you're wanting to do it while you're still within the initial processing loop.  At best, you can check between the loops to see whether the box you just identified aligns with any previous one.

Comment: @Prune Do you have an idea of how I could save these 2 rects with diferent names so I could mess a little with them individually? Like, name rect_1 the top one and rect_2 the bottom one. Your tips have been very helpful!

Comment: It's time to break this out as an answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's time to break this to a full answer.

After you identify each rectangle, compare its corners to each existing shape.  If it has the same color and a pair of corners in common (shared edge), then update the old rectangle: replace those two corners with the *other* corners of the new rectangle.

Add a couple of things to your code:

1. keep a list of the shapes found so far
2. as you find each shape, compare to the ones found already.

   rect_list = []

   for cnt in conts:
       area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)

   ```
   #filter noise
   if area > 25:

       M = cv2.moments(cnt)
       # ... several lines deleted
       rect = cv2.rectangle(green_bar_win, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255,0,0), 2)
       center = cv2.circle(green_bar_win, (cx, cy), 2, (0,0,255), 4)

       # Look for adjacent shapes here
       for old_rect in rect_list:
           # fetch the corners of old_rect
           # if old_rect has a pair of corners in common with
           #     the current rect, then merge the two.
           #     Do this by expanding the corners of old_rect.
           else:
               rect_list.append(rect)
   ```

Comment: lol I didn't think about using a list to store the rects, thanks man, really apreciate your help!